# SQL - exclude refunded transactions on new line

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have the following setup in the DB:

```
TransactionId | SequenceId | RefundedSequence | IsRefund
-------------------------------------------------------- 
1             | 1          | NULL             | false
1             | 2          | NULL             | false
1             | 3          | 1                | true
```

I.e. when a transaction is refunded, it gets a new SequenceId and the new SequenceId gets a reference to the refunded Sequence. With above example, SequenceId 3 refunded SequenceId 1. I now need to exclude all Transaction / SequenceIds that have been refunded, in above example TransactionId 1 / Sequence Id 1 needs to be excluded from my query, TransactionId 1 / SequenceId 2 not. My current solution to this is

```
SELECT TransactionId,
    SequenceId
FROM Transactions T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Transactions T2
        ON T1.TransactionId = T2.TransactionId
            AND T1.SequenceId = T2.RefundedSequence
WHERE T2.TransactionId IS NULL
    AND T1.IsRefund = false
```

Is there a more elegant way, i.e. without a selfjoin, to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t1.*
from Transactions t1
where isRefund = 'false' and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from Transactions t2
                  where t2.TransactionId = t1.TransactionId and 
                        t2.IsRefund = 'true'
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you consider it more elegant, but you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t2
                  where t2.TransactionId = t.TransactionId and
                        t2.RefundedSequence = t.SequenceId and
                 ) and
      t.isRefund is false;
```

This limits the filtering to the `where` clause, but it is essentially the same as your query.

Answer (score 1):

The relational operator your require is `EXCEPT`, a.k.a. `MINUS`:

```
SELECT TransactionId, SequenceId
  FROM Transactions
EXCEPT
SELECT TransactionId, SequenceId
  FROM Transactions
 WHERE TransactionId IS NULL
       AND IsRefund = 'false';
```

However, I find your table confusing: how do you define your constraints to ensure data integrity? Also there is no need to use nulls.

As a rule of thumb, when you struggle to write what should be a simple query (SQL DML), always question your design (SQL DDL).

Here is a suggested redesign, attempting to add (guess) the missing constraints, get rid of the nullable and 'flag' columns to attain a fully normalized design and ultimately make the query simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions
( TransactionId INT NOT NULL,
  SequenceId INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE ( SequenceId, TransactionId ) );

CREATE TABLE OpenRefunds
( TransactionId INT NOT NULL,
  RefundedSequence INT NOT NULL, 
  SequenceId INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE ( SequenceId, TransactionId ),
  UNIQUE ( RefundedSequence, TransactionId ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( RefundedSequence, TransactionId )
     REFERENCES Transactions ( SequenceId, TransactionId ),
  CHECK ( RefundedSequence < SequenceId ) );

CREATE TABLE ClosedRefunds
( TransactionId INT NOT NULL,
  RefundedSequence INT NOT NULL, 
  UNIQUE ( RefundedSequence, TransactionId ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( RefundedSequence, TransactionId )
     REFERENCES OpenRefunds ( RefundedSequence, TransactionId ) );

INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES
   ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 2 );

INSERT INTO OpenRefunds VALUES
   ( 1, 1, 3 );

INSERT INTO ClosedRefunds VALUES
   ( 1, 1 );

SELECT TransactionId, SequenceId
  FROM Transactions
EXCEPT
SELECT TransactionId, RefundedSequence
  FROM ClosedRefunds;
```

Comment: Thanks for the redesign. However, it is part of an external solution which is marketed worldwide, we're only one of many customers. So, I don't think they'll rewrite their whole system just for us. But yes, I agree that it would've been preferable to use another solution than this.

Comment: @Shade: do you know the constraints of the table to be able to reliably query it e.g. when RefundedSequence is null then IsRefunded is false, when IsRefunded is true then RefundedSequence is not null, when RefundedSequence is not null then RefundedSequence references a valid sequence number and TransactionId combination, etc?

Comment: No, don't know if that's the case. However, I've to say that the table is not that easy, e.g. there is no 'IsRefund' column, the 'IsRefund' is a combination of several columns. Instead of making the whole thing more complicated then necessary (if this is x and that y and ....), I narrowed it down to 'IsRefund'. A refund has some unique parameters but adding them to the example would've not served any purpose, I therefore combined them to 'IsRefund'.

Comment: @Shade OK, my point is that you can create an abstraction layer by coding your knowledge/assumptions about the data into views/procs and get your code to target the abstraction layer (over which you have control) rather than the vendor's data directly.

Comment: that is a great idea, gotta check with the DB Admin if I can do so. Thanks a lot for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

```
 With RefundTransaction(TransactionId,RefundedSequence)
 as
 (
 select TransactionId , RefundedSequence from Transactions  where IsRefund =true
 )
 select TransactionId, SequenceId from Transactions where IsRefund = false
 except 
 select TransactionId, RefundedSequence from RefundTransaction
```